# Flow throws "has no named export" when importing from "export *"

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, flowtype

I have a library that exports stuff

```
 // myLib.js
 export const foo = 'foo'
```

Then, I have a module that amongst other things re-exports everything from myLib.js

```
 // myModule.js
 export * from 'myLib' 
 export const bar = 'bar'
```

Then in `myComponent.js` I want to import stuff from `myModule.js`, that comes from `myLib.js`

```
 // myComponent.js
 import { foo, bar } from 'myModule'
 console.log( foo )
 console.log( bar )
```

The output of the console works, but flow throws an error in my IDE (Atom)

```
 Named import from module `myModle` This module has no named export called `foo``
```

Comment: I get no flow error. Maybe a restart of the flow server and Atom helps? You could also run flow in the console with just typing `flow` . You shouldn't get any error in the console. To restart the flow server type `flow stop` and `flow` to start it again.

Comment: I don't know what I did but it's not showing an error anymore

Comment: Yeah, sometimes a restart of the flow server and atom helps.